# Pandas merge values from two tables into on column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'd like to merge values from one table into a new column, and then merge any missing values from another table into that same column:

```
arr1 = pd.DataFrame(['a'],['b'],['c'])
arr2 = pd.DataFrame(['a',1],['b',2])
arr3 = pd.DataFrame(['c',3])


output = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3']]
```

Joining arr2 and arr3 and then merging is not an option because they have different number of columns in my actual application of this.

Comment: Can you put your expected output dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat` to concatenate `arr2` and `arr3`. It will take care of any extra columns by filling missing data with `nan`. Let's add an extra column to your data to show how this works:

```
arr2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,'extra column'],['b',2,'extra column']], index=None)
arr3 = pd.DataFrame([['c',3]], index=None)
```

`arr2`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | extra column |
| 1 | b | 2 | extra column |

`arr3`:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | c | 3 |

Then concatenate:

```
new_df = pd.concat([arr2, arr3], ignore_index=True)
```

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | extra column |
| 1 | b | 2 | extra column |
| 2 | c | 3 | nan |

**Update:** To tackle the dataframe not fitting in memory you could use `dask`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

arr2 = pd.DataFrame([['a',1,'extra column'],['b',2,'extra column']], index=None)
arr3 = pd.DataFrame([['c',3]], index=None)

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(arr2, 1)
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(arr3, 1)

dd_final = dd.concat([ddf1, ddf2])
```

Output `dd_final.compute()`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 1 | extra column |
| 1 | b | 2 | extra column |
| 0 | c | 3 | nan |

Comment: Another problem is that arr1 is 60gb, and concat creates a copy. I dont have the ram to do a concat. Is there any other way?

Comment: @helloimgeorgia ah I see. I have updated the answer with a possible solution